# Multiple ways to add an entry?

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app, I have multiple ways to add an entry to a list. I have the plus button at the top right, like in this picture:

[image]

The user has three ways to add an entry to the list. However, the plus button only can lead to one model view controller. I have three currently (one per option), and I would like the user to select the one of the three options to add an entry. What is the best way to present this?

Answer (score 1):

iOS (and other mobile platforms) support a modal view (a rough example is shown below):

[image: Modal example]

You can present a modal view when adding a new row to allow the user to select the entry method (then redirecting to the appropriate edit screen).